# Prestashop set catalog mode ON/OFF if user unlogged/logged

Tags: javascript, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm working on a prestashop module to set the catalog mode ON or OFF if user is unlogged or logged.

Works great but got a problem.

I don't want unlogged users see prices at all and allowed to order. But with the solution I found, when first connection (mode catalog OFF) unlogged user load the page, the catalog mod turn ON, but he can see prices (has to reload to hide prices) So, first load set catalog mode ON and second load display real catalog mode.

I found a js script to reload automatically to take effect with the new mode but obviously, loading time of the page is two times longer.

Here is the function :

```
  public function hookHeader()
    {
      $logged = $this->context->customer->isLogged();
      if (!$logged) {
        Configuration::updateValue('PS_CATALOG_MODE', true);
      } else {
        Configuration::updateValue('PS_CATALOG_MODE', false);
      }
      // reload the page once more
      echo '
        <script type="text/javascript">
          (function() {
            if( window.localStorage ) {
              if( !localStorage.getItem( "firstLoad" ) ) {
                localStorage[ "firstLoad" ] = true;
                window.location.reload();
              } else {
                localStorage.removeItem( "firstLoad" );
              }
            }
          })();
        </script>
      ';
    }
```

Hope somebody could help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution has a problem.
You're updating the value inside the database: if multiple users are browsing the site, the value will be turned on/off/on/off/..., in other words it's "unstable".
The next customer that visits the site will get the current value (can be on and off).

Instead, you should toggle the value only for that customer. I wrote an override for `Configuration` class, that check if you're trying to get `PS_CATALOG_MODE`, then check if you'er logged in and returns `0 or 1`. Be careful to cache this value using `static` variables (so you don't have to check multiple times).

But this solution has a flaw too. It checks the key of the request configuration variable everytime.

A better solution would be to change the value of this during the session. Configuration variables are actually held in a PHP array during the session.
You should change it here:

https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/classes/Configuration.php#L203

possibly by overridding

https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/classes/Configuration.php#L140

**This is what I had in mind by overriding** `loadConfiguration`:

```
<?php

// placed in /override/classes/Configuration.php

class Configuration extends ConfigurationCore
{
    public static function loadConfiguration()
    {
        parent::loadConfiguration();
        // 'global' because I assume you're not runing multishop
        self::$_cache[self::$definition['table']][0]['global']['PS_CATALOG_MODE'] = !Context::getContext()->customer->isLogged();
    }
}
```

I wrote this from memeroy so be sure to check the anmes, etc. I assume you're running > PS1.6

Comment: Thank for the informations. I see what you mean by "unstable" but it was the easiest way I found. I saw the function loadConfiguration you were talking about but I'm affrayed I'm not good enough to custom it my self. BTW, it seems to be THE solution.  
May you give me more informations/tips to override it the best way, please ? I'll be glad if I can learn how to do it and improve myself. 
Thanks again.

Comment: Hi ! Followed your tips and it works great but I'm not so sure I'm doing it right. May you check this code and tell me if it's good or if it has to be improved ? http://pastebin.com/jV7EcYb5
If you can confirm this code is good, I'll edit the question with this to share the solution. Thanks !

Comment: @AdrienLeber I updated my answer with `LoadConfiguration` override

Comment: Waw, it's really better than what I made with the get() function. Thank you, I learned something useful. Have a great sunday. ; )

Comment: @AdrienLeber Thanks! Does it work? I also forgot to put negation on the value

Comment: No, it doesn't work 'cause the Context is not set yet so all keys have NULL values. `object(Context)#4 (19) { ["cart"]=> NULL ["customer"]=> NULL ["cookie"]=> NULL ["link"]=> NULL ["country"]=> NULL ["employee"]=> NULL ["controller"]=> NULL ["override_controller_name_for_translations"]=> NULL ["language"]=> NULL ["currency"]=> NULL ["tab"]=> NULL ["shop"]=> NULL ["theme"]=> NULL ["smarty"]=> NULL ["mobile_detect"]=> NULL ["mode"]=> NULL ["mobile_device":protected]=> NULL ["is_mobile":protected]=> NULL ["is_tablet":protected]=> NULL } `

Comment: So, I kept the override of the get() function. But change the way to get "logged" value to use context instead of $cookie. 
`return !Context::getContext()->customer->isLogged() || self::$_cache[self::$definition['table']][$id_lang]['global'][$key];`
And it works well for now. Do you know how to getContext() from the loadConfigation() function ?

Comment: You're right. The `loadConfiguration` is called early, before defining customer object. You're still comparing the key value every time someone tries to get a config variable, which may slow down the shop just slightly. I'd still try to overwrite the loaded value at the correct moment, but it this works for you I suppose its ok

Comment: Ok, you can ring my bell if you find a better way to do it. Many thanks dude. Your help is really appreciated. = ) I'll share the override we build in a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the group settings? Customer group settings allow you to set the "show prices" option to "false" for visitors, and "true" for customers, for example.

Comment: Thank you for that answer but since previous reply, I understood I got the write the module in a other way. Thanks for your tip !

Answer (score 0):

The solution we find with gskema is to override the get() function of the Configuration class :

```
<?php

// placed in /override/classes/Configuration.php

class Configuration extends ConfigurationCore
{
  public static function get($key, $id_lang = null, $id_shop_group = null, $id_shop = null)
  {
      if (defined('_PS_DO_NOT_LOAD_CONFIGURATION_') && _PS_DO_NOT_LOAD_CONFIGURATION_) {
          return false;
      }

      // If conf if not initialized, try manual query
      if (!isset(self::$_cache[self::$definition['table']])) {
          Configuration::loadConfiguration();
          if (!self::$_cache[self::$definition['table']]) {
              return Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT `value` FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.bqSQL(self::$definition['table']).'` WHERE `name` = "'.pSQL($key).'"');
          }
      }
      $id_lang = (int)$id_lang;
      if ($id_shop === null || !Shop::isFeatureActive()) {
          $id_shop = Shop::getContextShopID(true);
      }
      if ($id_shop_group === null || !Shop::isFeatureActive()) {
          $id_shop_group = Shop::getContextShopGroupID(true);
      }

      if (!isset(self::$_cache[self::$definition['table']][$id_lang])) {
          $id_lang = 0;
      }

      if ($id_shop && Configuration::hasKey($key, $id_lang, null, $id_shop)) {
          if($key == 'PS_CATALOG_MODE' && Context::getContext()->controller->controller_type == 'front')
          {
              return !Context::getContext()->customer->isLogged() || self::$_cache[self::$definition['table']][$id_lang]['shop'][$id_shop][$key];
          } else {
              return self::$_cache[self::$definition['table']][$id_lang]['shop'][$id_shop][$key];
          }
      } elseif ($id_shop_group && Configuration::hasKey($key, $id_lang, $id_shop_group)) {
          if($key == 'PS_CATALOG_MODE' && Context::getContext()->controller->controller_type == 'front')
          {
              return !Context::getContext()->customer->isLogged() || self::$_cache[self::$definition['table']][$id_lang]['group'][$id_shop_group][$key];
          } else {
              return self::$_cache[self::$definition['table']][$id_lang]['group'][$id_shop_group][$key];
          }
      } elseif (Configuration::hasKey($key, $id_lang)) {
          if($key == 'PS_CATALOG_MODE' && Context::getContext()->controller->controller_type == 'front')
          {
              return !Context::getContext()->customer->isLogged() || self::$_cache[self::$definition['table']][$id_lang]['global'][$key];
          } else {
              return self::$_cache[self::$definition['table']][$id_lang]['global'][$key];
          }
      }
      return false;
  }
}
```

/!\ still comparing the key value every time someone tries to get a config variable, which may slow down the shop just slightly.

**EDIT**

Add a condition if Context is front office to fixe back office issue 'Call isLogged on NULL'